# KeyPressed Not Working

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, keylistener

I am trying to move an image up and down by using arrow keys.I have used ASCII values to check which key is pressed, but the handler for `keyPressed` is not getting called. I checked by applying a breakpoint but nothing happens.

```
package com.google.play;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ShootingBubble extends JPanel implements ActionListener,KeyListener {

    int y=250;
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawRect(0, 200, 300, 400);
        g.fillRect(0, 200, 300, 400);

        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawRect(800, 200, 300, 400);
        g.fillRect(800, 200, 300, 400);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(1000,200, 350, 200);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawOval(295, 190, 20, 20);
        g.fillOval(295, 190, 20, 20);

        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(0,190, 300, 190);


        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(310,190, 310, y);

        ImageIcon ic=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\mario.gif");
        ic.paintIcon(this, g, 295, y);//moving image with help of y variable
        ic.paintIcon(this, g, 0, 150);
        ic.paintIcon(this, g, 40, 150);
        ic.paintIcon(this, g, 80, 150);
        ic.paintIcon(this, g, 120, 150);

        ImageIcon ic1=new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\index.jpg");
        ic1.paintIcon(this, g, 320, 130);





    }

    public ShootingBubble() {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);


    }


    void init(){

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("c");

    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("d");

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShootingBubble st=new ShootingBubble();
        JFrame jf=new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(1000, 600);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.getContentPane().add(st);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        }





    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {

        if(arg0.getKeyCode()==38){

            y-=2;//updating image position in vertically upward direction
        }
        if(arg0.getKeyCode()==40)
        {
            y=y+2;//updating image position in vertically downward direction
        }


        System.out.println("Key Pressed "+arg0.getKeyCode()+ " "+arg0.getKeyChar());
        repaint();;

    }



}
```

Comment: Please simplify your question whenever you ask. Whatever you wanted to ask is clearly get mentioned. As this is your first question. ll give upvote for you. Go though tutorial, help about how to ask question and maintain standers

Answer (score 4):

Several problems, not all related to the KeyListener:

1. Don't do I/O in the paintComponent() method. The painting methods are for painting only. Swing will determine when the component needs to be repainted and you don't want to continually read the image over and over. Read the image in your constructor.
2. All components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame.setVisible(...) method is invoked. This will make sure the layout manager is invoked on all components.
3. Don't use "magic numbers". I have no idea what "38" and "40" are. How do you even know what they are? If you copied that code from a tutorial then dump the tutorial! Instead you should use `KeyEvent.VK_???`
4. Even if you add the KeyListener to the frame, the code probably won't work, because KeyEvents are only dispatched to the component with focus and I don't know the frame will always have focus. Really the panel should have focus since it is the component doing the painting.
5. Don't use a KeyListener. Swing was designed to by used with `Key Bindings`. See [Motion With the Keyboard](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information and examples.

Answer (score 3):

You have to register the keylistener.

add `jf.addKeyListener(this);` to your main method.